# Defiant security light installed..Motion senser flashes red But no lights

Tags: wiring

I just purchased a new Defiant model# DFI 5852 BK security light to replace an older one. After installation..the motion sensor flashes red but lights do not come on..Tried adjusting sensitivity, & Test modes, No change..

Comment: Is it daylight?

Answer (score 1):

The sensor flashing red is telling you that the sensor sees you.  It's not turning on because only a fool would turn the lights on in broad daylight.  Yes, it knows it is broad daylight because it also has a light sensor.

If it is in fact night, then you have an unusual amount of artificial lighting in the area, and that is fooling the sensor.  However, most sensors have a learning feature *if you leave the system energized 24x7*, and after a couple day/night cycles it will learn what normal light levels are *here*.

If you cut power to the sensor, you will wipe its memory and it will have to start the learning process all over again.  So don't do that.